# Keep Getting "Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled" in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Whenever I start a spring boot project I keep getting this error, This question has been asked multiple times on stakeoverflow I have tried all the solutions but nothing works for me. My first questions are what is the reason for this error, and how can I fix it.

FilterApplication.java

```
package com.example.filter;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication()
public class FilterApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FilterApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

FilterConnector.java

```
package com.example.filter;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class FilterConnector {

    @Autowired
    private FilterService filterService;
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public List<Filter> home()
    {

        return this.filterService.getData();
    }
}
```

FilterService.java

```
package com.example.filter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class FilterService {
    @Autowired
    private FilterDao filterDao;

    public List<Filter> getData() {
        System.out.println("----------------------HERE-------------");
        return this.filterDao.findAll();
    }
}
```

FilterDao.java

```
package com.example.filter;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface FilterDao extends JpaRepository<Filter, Integer> {

}
```

Comment: And did you re-run your application in debug mode to display the conditions? What did they say?

Comment: please provide full stack trace of error

Answer (score 0):

Spring framework relies on ApplicationContext to inject dependencies into the dependent object. For example your FilterDao will be inject into FilterService object.

To do this Spring will try to initialized instances of these classes at the start of the Application, but if it fails you will see this error message.

The problem with your code is related to FilterDao class, Spring can't initialize an instance of this class because it requires the Database to be configured correctly.

**To fix this error:**

- you need to check your database connection is correct.
- make sure there is a table corresponding to Filter class.
- check the primary key (ID) is actually of type Integer.

If you provide full error stack I can give you a specific solution.

*Note:
The issues is not related to FilterService or FilterConnector, because you are using @Autowired annotation implying the dependencies are optional and they will be injected after the bean initialization.*

Comment: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: As the error message suggests check the database connection and make sure you have a database instance running and the connection string is correct in Spring configuration.